# Python addition to array subset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an image, which is an array:

```
self.imgData[0]
```

I do some operations already such as:

```
self.imgData[0] = self.imgData[0] * scalar
```

which will multiply every pixel in the image by scalar

```
self.imgData[0][self.imgData[0] < -32767] = -32767
```

for any pixel less than -32767 set to -32767

these both work fine, but when I try to use addition or subtraction:

```
self.imgData[0][self.imgData[0] > 0] += 100.0
```

nothing is happening. and I do not know why, can any one help?

Comment: What do `type(self.imgData[0])` and `np.shape(self.imgData[0])` return?

Comment: type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

shape: (2048, 2048)

Comment: It should work as expected. Are you sure there are any pixels with positive values in your data?